# Object-c ,How to dynamically declare a type or method of input text, similar to PHP's eval()

Tags: objective-c

How to dynamically declare a type or method of input text, similar to PHP's eval(),
I need to use the input text as a concrete implementation of a function when the program is running.

```
  //fake code
    NSString * inputText = @"-(int)process{int i = 1; int a = i; return a + 1;}";

[self eval(inputText)];
[self process];
```

Comment: Objective c is compiled, not interpreted like PHP so you can't simply evaluate a string at runtime; you will need to create you own parser and expression evaluation engine

Comment: You can dynamically call selectors from string though. But not as powerful as what you are trying to do

Comment: So can OC be like C++ can call methods like DLL files?
If my problem can be solved, I can call the input text and the template generated by my own and compile it into a dynamic link library.

Comment: You can't compile new code based on user input at run time

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible, as commented by Paul. But you can leverage Objective-Cs dynamic runtime to somewhat achieve what you want to do. But I don't think it will fit all your use cases tho.

Try looking at selectors, NSInvocation and see if it will fulfil your needs.

Comment: So can OC be like C++ can call methods like DLL files?
If my problem can be solved, I can call the input text and the template generated by my own and compile it into a dynamic link library.

Comment: You can combine OC and C++ so why not go down that path, make the C++ call DLL files and OC access the C++ classes. Don't have any experience here though